how are typos that are direct contradictions handled?
For example, if these sentences are written in the specifications:
The widget A is configurable.
The list A has four options.
But the patent drafter actually means to write:
The widget A is not configurable.
The list A has five options.
Can these types of typos be corrected?


Can these types of typos be corrected?

IIRC, they can be corrected only if it can be done in a way that does not introduce new matter. Both the error and it's resolution must be clear to a person of ordinary skill from reading the original.
Sometimes the context provides sufficient support for fixing a typo and sometimes it doesn't. Avoid filing anything that hasn't been proof-read at least a few times.
